# How to use a static public IP address and DNS label when creating new aks cluster in bicep template?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-bicep

I am new to bicep and have created a bicep template that deploys a new managed aks cluster. One of the objects that it creates is a public ip address in the second resource group (example "MC_test-aks-cluster_westeurope")

How can I reference in the bicep template to use static public IP address and DNS label in the public IP address object (created in the second resource group "MC_test-aks-cluster_westeurope") when a new managed aks cluster is deployed?

I can add it on an existing cluster using the portal or create a new public ip address object I have build the new cluster by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip). However I want to add in the template to avoid this additional step.

Comment: So you are trying to re-use the same ip for multiple cluster / Not sure to understand what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The `MC_` resource group is [managed by the Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks) - you shouldn't typically be deploying resources to it. You should be putting your resources in your own resource group, and using Kubernetes Manifest annotations to point to the resources.

[image: manifest annotation for resource group]

Here's a detailed guide on doing your exact IP and DNS scenario : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip